# Java Regex get word

Tags: java, regex

How to get by regex only 'byDate' in @byDate(@RP(@NOW())

Comment: By doing research and demonstrating the slightest bit of effort.

Comment: `"@byDate(@RP(@NOW())".replaceFirst("@(.*?)\\(@.*", "$1")`

Comment: @YCF_L Works fine! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This regular expresion will find all chanracters between the first `@` and the first `(` :

```
(?<!\(@)(?<=@)[^\(]+
```